# My action runner for github is failing. How do I resolve yarn: command not found. Process completed with exit code 127?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, yarnpkg

[image]

I was running a self hosted github action runner but my jobs were failing with this error message in the picture. I searched stackoverflow before posting the question but couldn't find any relevant threads. Let me know if there are threads that I missed.

How do I resolve this error so that my github action runner can run my CI builds again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in GitHub Action runners have yarn installed on them by default but a self-hosted runner won't unless you install it.  See relevant issue here: https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/182.

If you don't want to install yarn on your self-hosted runner you can install it in the workflows that need it.  Just make sure to uninstall it afterward to keep your self-hosted runners clean.

```
# You'll need to make sure node is installed first
- name: Install Node
  uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version-file: '.node-version'

- name: Install yarn
  run: npm install -g yarn

# Do what you need to do with yarn

# Uninstall when you're done
- name: Clean up
  if: always()
  run: npm uninstall -g yarn
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add the step:

```
- name: Install yarn
  run: corepack enable
```

And cleanup the file after local testing.